# Is the singleton graph 2-connected?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

Whether the [singleton graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingletonGraph.html) is connected, depends on the definition:

> **(1)** A graph is said to be connected if every pair of vertices in the graph
>   is connected.
>   (Wikipedia, [Connected graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_graph#Definitions_of_components.2C_cuts_and_connectivity))

According to this definition, the singleton graph (without loop) is connected when one interprets "pair of vertices" as "pair of distinct vertices". Otherwise, it is not.

> **(2)** A graph G is said to be $k$-connected if it has more than $k$ vertices and the result of deleting any set of fewer than $k$ vertices is a connected graph.
>   (Wikipedia, [$k$-vertex-connected graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph))

According to this definition, the singleton graph is *not* connected. It would be when  "exactly or more than $k$ vertices" was meant? Even then it would be not 2-connected.

> **(3)** A graph G is said to be $k$-connected if there does not exist a set of
>   $k-1$ vertices whose removal disconnects the graph.
>   (Wolfram's MathWorld, [$k$-connected graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-ConnectedGraph.html))

According to this definition, the singleton graph is connected. Whether the singleton graph is 2-connected depends on whether the [null graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NullGraph.html) is connected. According to this definition, it is.

Is it just a matter of taste, whether one considers the null and the singleton graph as  connected, resp. 2-connected? And when does it matter?

(Consider the case, that one wants to prove that the connected components of every graph do cover the graph. They would not, when the singleton graphs were not considered connected.)

Comment: A point is always connected to itself, right?

Comment: Also in graphs? What then is the difference between a point with and without a loop? And even when I agree (what I do): Is it always 2-connected, too?

Comment: Note that connected and $2$-connected mean different things. The notion of connected is the same thing as $1$-connected, and the singleton graph is $1$ connected, but it is not $k$-connected for $k \geq 2$.